# Biblioteca para gerar arquivos referente a uma classe de forma autônoma?

Tags: java, java-ee

Por exemplo eu crio a classe cachorro ai depois eu tenho que criar os arquivos cachorroBO, cachorroDAO, cachorroDAOImpl. Eu queria saber se tem um forma de automatizar isso, criando apenas a classe e depois esses outros arquivos sendo gerados pela biblioteca.

Comment: Você pode usar Snippets da sua IDE.

Comment: Eu pesquisei antes de fazer a pergunta e não tinha encontrado nada, sabe me dizer se o eclipse tem nativo ou precisa de algum plugin da loja?

Comment: tem nativo, não é totalmente automático, mas tem plugins que talvez resolvam com mais especificidade. https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-coded-templates-or-code-snippets#group-details

Comment: Obrigado, vou da uma olhada.